# Why do we have to use octahedral voids for formula making in solid state chemistry?

Tags: solid-state-chemistry

Allow me to take an example to explain myself.

**Q)** What is the formula of a compound in which the element Y forms a ccp lattice and an atom of X occupy ${1\over3}$rd of tetrahedral voids?

Now to find the formula we first say that the space occupied by octahedral voids are $2$*space occupied by tetrahedral voids = $2\over3$.

No. of atoms of element X = $2\over3$*no. of octahedral voids
$\implies$ No. of atoms of element X = ${2\over3} \times 4$ = $8\over3$

Ratio of X and Y = ${8\over3}:4$ = $2:3$

$\therefore$ formula is $X_2Y_3$.

**Coming to my question -** Why can't we use space occupied by tetrahedral voids?

Comment: We don't have to use the octahedral voids. This is nonsense.

Comment: This is how my teacher and my textbook shows it. I'm new to all this so I don't know a whole lot.

Comment: We have twice as many tetrahedral voids as lattice-forming atoms, hence 2*Y. We only use $1\over3$ of them, hence the number of $X={2\over3}Y$, which gives the formula $\ce{X2Y3}$. That's how I show it.

Comment: Aren't you using the concept I used indirectly? Coz number of lattice forming atoms = number of octahedral voids (as far as my knowledge goes).

Comment: That's right, which also explains why we've got the same result. It is just that we don't have to mention the octahedral voids anywhere.

Comment: Ohh okay. Thank you for helping. I appreciate it!

Comment: @HarshDarji if you got your answer, feel free to self answer it. Self-answer are appreciated and it also help future readers.